# Httpd Directory read permissions only issue

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, redhat, httpd

In my scenario ,I need the 'httpd' directory in '/var/log/' to be readable by the users in 'devs' group (Amazon Linux 2) Could anyone guide me how to accomplish this?

We have a few developers who maintain the system and I want them to easily read the log files in /var/log/httpd without needing root access.

can this will help ??

```
chmod -R go+r /var/log/httpd
```

or `chmod -R go+rX /var/log/httpd`

or do i need to go with :

```
chmod 644 /var/log/httpd

chgrp -R apache /var/log/httpd
chmod 02750 /var/log/httpd
chmod 0640 /var/log/httpd/*
create 0640 root apache
```

ls

```
[root@ip-10-0-10-165 httpd]# ls -la
total 48
drwx------ 19 root   devs   4096 Apr  3 03:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   devs   4096 Apr  8 07:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Feb 15 14:55 access_log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u1-dev.qwerty.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   1648 Apr  3 03:42 error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    883 Mar 13 03:41 error_log-20220313
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u4-dev.qwerty.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     41 Mar  1 20:44 langs.qwerty.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u8-dev3.qwerty.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Feb 15 14:55 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    314 Apr  3 03:42 ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    157 Mar  6 03:50 ssl_error_log-20220313
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Feb 15 14:55 ssl_request_log
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache  253 Apr  3 03:42 www.qwerty.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u13-dev.qwerty.com
[root@ip-10-0-20-173 httpd]#
```

How to modifying those permission set? what is the best approach here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use acl for this directory and grant permissions for devs group. For example:

```
setfacl -m g:devs:rx httpd/
```

You can set file access list for a directory. In your example you have httpd directory with permissions set for user/group root only.

```
# ls -la| grep httpd
drwx------   2 root     root        4096 Apr  8 10:11 httpd
```

You can check that this directory have no acl list:

```
getfacl httpd/
# file: httpd/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

We set permissions for the devs group with read and execute permissions:

```
setfacl -m g:devs:rx httpd/
```

After setting the permissions, it will look like this:

```
getfacl httpd/
# file: httpd/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
group:devs:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Note the extra sign (+) about any existing acl on the ls command.

```
# ls -la| grep httpd
drwxr-x---+  2 root     root        4096 Apr  8 10:11 httpd
```

It might be a good idea to repeat the setfacl command with the -b switch to set the default permissions. I usually do that.

```
-d, --default
           All operations apply to the Default ACL. Regular ACL entries in the input set are promoted to Default ACL entries. Default ACL entries in the input set are discarded. (A warning  is  issued
           if that happens).
```

Regards

Comment: just for better understanding , can you describe a bit with example ?

Comment: I expanded the answer above.

Comment: KuchnMar ,  setfacl -m g:devs:rx /var/log/httpd , will grant my  'devs' group to provide the desire permission without root access right  ?                                                  [root@ip-10-0-10-165 httpd]# getfacl /var/log/httpd
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/log/httpd
# owner: root
# group: devs
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
"

Answer (score 0):

According to how you tagged the question, you are using a Redhat-style environment. Assuming you are using the stock Apache httpd installation, you are probably, behind-the-scenes, dealing with logrotate. Out of the box, logrotate executes daily out of `/etc/cron.daily`. It will move your current log files out of the way, create new ones and restart `httpd` such that it will begin to use the newly created, empty log files.

Check `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`. For example, the stock version shows:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

If you add a line like this within the curly brackets, logrotate will properly rotate and re-create your log files with the correct owner and group memberships:

```
    create 0640 root devs
```

This instructs logrotate to create the new log files with `root` as the owner, `devs` as the group, with permissions being owner read/write and group read.

You can then set your httpd log directory with permissions and ownerships like so:

```
chown root:devs /var/log/httpd
chmod 0750 /var/log/httpd
```

For the first day, you may also want to manually set the permissions on the log files and logrotate will pick up on the following days:

```
chown root:devs /var/log/httpd/*log
chmod 0640 /var/log/httpd/*log
```

You can get fancy with ACLs as demonstrated by @KuchnMar above, but this solution keeps things simple and compatible across various *nix and filesystem types.

This may be similar on a Debian-style host, but your logrotate configuration file may be called `apache2` instead.

More information can be found here:

- logrotate: https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate
- mod_log_config: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html